# Expression "N-fold" eg the stock value went up 3-fold

Tags: meaning, etymology

Where does the expression x-fold come from? And is its current usage the same as when it originated?

For example, if you fold a piece of paper n times, the thickness is not n times the original times n, but 2 to the power of n. So 5 folds means the thickness is actually multiplied by 32, not 5. Yet saying something increases 5-fold means it's 5 times greater.

Answer (score 0):

This is the suffix [*-fold*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-fold), which has nothing to do with the verb *to fold* semantically, although they are related etymologically.

Comment: That's right. Fold here means three times some value.